# Coverting for loop to lambda and streams

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I have this block of code and have spent some time trying to convert this for loop, using lambda expressions and streams but have failed.

```
for(int i = 0, j = 308; i < 17;i++, j -= 18) {
            if(consoleMessages[i] != null) {
                newBoldFont.drawBasicString(consoleMessages[i], 9, j, 16777215, 0);
            }
        }
```

I have tried this, also have tried many other ways but can't remember what I had.

```
Arrays.stream(consoleMessages).forEach(x->{
            IntStream.range(308,0).map(inty->inty-=18).forEach(v->{
                newBoldFont.drawBasicString(x, 9, v, 16777215, 0);
                return;
            });
        });
```

Comment: Show what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

If you insist...

```
    IntStream.range(0, 17)
        .forEach(
            i-> {
                if(consoleMessages[i] != null)
                    newBoldFont.drawBasicString(consoleMessages[i], 9, 308 - 18 * i, 16777215, 0);
            });
```

... but WHY would anyone want to do this? The loop is perfect, it is readable, it is understandable. Leave the code as it is.

Comment: The Stream code would become significantly better with a `filter` operation…

Comment: @Holger Yes, but you'd loose the relation to the index that way. Or do you have any idea how to keep this? (Apart from doing a search in the array to determine the index or use an intermediate "pair" object.)

Comment: I’m not talking about `map`ping, just filtering, `.filter(i -> consoleMessages[i] != null).forEach(i -> newBoldFont.drawBasicString(consoleMessages[i], 9, 308 - 18 * i, 16777215, 0))`…